# Google Play Android Developer API not giving complete released bundle version code information

Tags: google-apis-explorer

When I request Google Play Android Developer API to fetch the released bundles using the below request
TRACK_INFO=$(curl -X GET 
-H "Authorization: ***" 
"https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/{package_id}/edits/{edit_id}/bundles")

by this request I am getting only few released bundle information only , I want all released bundles information. Duly checked service account permissions and all, everything looks good.